# Remote SDR on the internet other than WebSDR?

Tags: software-defined-radio, internet

Besides WebSDR, what remote Software-Defined-Radio stations (for shortwave or amateur bands) might be available for open public access over the internet?

What protocols do these SDR stations use to stream data over the internet?  Do any of these SDR stations use open source or published standard APIs for control and data?

Answer (score 5):

The question specifies "SDR", but if all you want is to listen to signals in a distant location, you might try http://www.globaltuners.com/.

Answer (score 5):

OpenWebRX is another way to monitor an SDR online.

http://sdr.hu/openwebrx

If you go to http://sdr.hu/ you can also  see a list of receivers you can listen in to.

(As to your other questions, those might be better split out.  These days there exist many ways to handle the needs of a remote monitoring client written for the browser.  I would guess both WebSDR and OpenWebRX use WebSockets to constantly push data to the clients but other than that I'm not sure what you're asking.)

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question:

WebSDR seems to stream demodulated audio via using private (closed) API for control.

A couple other possible solutions for streaming remote SDR data over the internet include:

rtl_tcp : You can build your own remote SDR station with an RTL-SDR (or similar SDR) on a tiny server (Raspberry Pi 3, et.al.), and stream data over the network using the rtl_tcp protocol. See: https://github.com/steve-m/librtlsdr

OpenWebRX: http://sdr.hu/openwebrx

Cloud-SDR: http://www.cloud-sdr.com/

These all seem to use open protocols and/or open source software.

Added:

[rsp_tcp](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/tag/rsp_tcp/) is a rtl-tcp workalike for SDRPlay RSP receivers/devices.

Comment: Also, I wrote hfp_tcp for the AirSpy HF+ SDR receiver USB peripheral: https://github.com/hotpaw2/hfp_tcp

Answer (score 3):

Here https://f1atb.fr/index.php/2021/05/03/remote-sdr-v2-2/ you have a Remote SDR solution I developed last year
73
F1ATB

Comment: Salut André, et bienvenue à ham.stackexchange.com!  Thank you for disclosing that you are the creator of the software that you recommend.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to this site. Is this, as the question asks, available for open public access over the internet? Also, link-only answers are not recommended on Stack Exchange as links may stop working. If the link contains some relevant information, please quote it in your answer.

Comment: André is recommending software that he wrote that can be used to set up a remote SDR system, @MikeWaters.  As far as I can tell there is no publicly-available system.  However the question also asks about open-source software, which is what he wrote.  Since his answer is about software, I think a link to the site for the software is appropriate as an answer.